# How can I correct my address when filing federal and state income taxes with H&R Block Online?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

If I filed taxes using H&R Block Online with my current address and it put me filing taxes from a previous residence, how do I go about filing taxes for my new residence?

Comment: What country? Its also not clear when you are already filing with your current address, what is your new residence?

Answer (score 1):

You can update your address with the IRS using [form 8822](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8822.pdf). You can also do it through the ["Where is my refund" system online](http://www.irs.gov/Refunds). See the detailed information about [how to update your address with the IRS here](http://www.irs.gov/Help-&-Resources/Tools-&-FAQs/FAQs-for-Individuals/Frequently-Asked-Tax-Questions-&-Answers/IRS-Procedures/Address-Changes/Address-Changes).